# Oracle query show minimum record in SQL plus but show all records in Enterprise management

Tags: mysql, date, plsql, oracle10g

I tried to get all record from pl/sql with date criteria but it does not show all record in application and SQLplus but show all record in enterprise management.

Here is my query:

```
select position_num,budgeted_status,effective_from from
  HRISAKHSP2011.position,HRISAKHSP2011.designation
  where position.position_title=designation.code and position_num not in 
  (select position_num from HRISAKHSP2011.position_workhistory 
  where expired=0) 
  and (position_status='AC') 
  and to_date(effective_from,'dd/mm/yy') <=to_date('31/01/15','dd/mm/yy') 
  order by budgeted_status
```

I think there is problem in date criteria it shows all record greater then  **01/01/2000**.

Comment: `to_date(effective_from,'dd/mm/yy')` Why are you using **TO_DATE** on a **DATE**?

Comment: @LalitKumarB: How do you know that `effective_from` is a DATE column?

Comment: @Thilo: If it isn't, we have another issue to talk about...

Comment: @Thilo Ideally, it should be **DATE** data type. Else, f it not, then it is another issue.

Comment: Its date data type and thankyou Lalit after removing to_date from effective_from it start showing all result